# Changing to join instead of sub query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, inner-join

```
    SELECT 
        a.id, MIN(s.datetime), 
        MAX(s.datetime), 
        MIN(s.id)
   FROM asdt a
   inner join alm al on id = al.id,
   sta s
   WHERE 
        a.id not in (select id from alm where distance <= a.radius )
        GROUP BY a.id
```

This query runs very slow due to subquery when it is checking the distance against **a.radius** from the upper table.

Comment: Your problem isn't the sub-query / join sintaxis. You have index?. How many rows are in  sta? Because you are multiplying cardinality of `a * al * s` . 
 Anyway Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: Your query is not syntactically correct (two commas in a `from` clause is even worse than one).  You should provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: ^^^^^^^ that's pretty funny.  @johnny don't mix join notation stick with the more current standard and avoid `,` in the from clause.  and... did you really mean to cross join to sta?  how does sta relate to asdt or alm?  that's likely the biggest performance hog.

Comment: I have tried to simplify the query in here, in fact, it is a complex query. The is just the typo in the question. So when I take out the distance <= a.radius it is super fast. The sta table is big table.

Comment: maybe you need to create a index on column distance, but a more especifc analysis is requiered to determined that. If you want just eliminate de subquery you need to do a left join instead a inner and add a new condition in your where... try it. LEFT instead INNER. Something like that: left join alm al on a.id = al.id and distance <= a.radius, sta s
  And in your where, replace it to: distance is null

Comment: I will update the question with every information.

Comment: Try `... WHERE  not exists (select 1  from alm where id = a.id and distance <= a.radius )`

Comment: @Abelisto that did the trick. As I said my query is very complex and does a lot of GIS calculation and this was the only place slowing it down so I simplified it in the question and removed all other parts of the query and kept it this way. Thanks

Comment: @johnny You are welcome. In many cases `not exists (<subquery>)` more efficient then `not in (<subquery>)`. In the future just try both.